# SystemSensorManager and missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors, android-vibration

I use `SensorManager` and `Vibrator`.

I implemented like this in `onCreate()`:

```
    sensorMgr = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    sensorMgr!!.registerListener(this@MainActivity, SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)
```

in `onDestroy()`

```
    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (sensorMgr != null) {
            sensorMgr!!.unregisterListener(this@MainActivity)
        }
        sensorMgr = null
        vibrator = null

        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

I have an error like this:

```
MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.hardware.SystemSensorManager that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

I don't use any receivers. So, I have no idea what it says.

What's wrong with it and How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is this an activity?

Answer (score 0):

Update it like this, because we can't completely rely on `onStop` and `onDestroy` because it's not assured that it will get called, that is causing your issue. So it's better to register on `onResume` and unregister on `onPause`

```
override fun onCreate(){
    super.onCreate()
    sensorMgr = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
}
```

Register it on

```
override fun onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    sensorMgr?.registerListener(this@MainActivity, SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME)
}
```

unregister it on `onPause()`

```
override fun onPause(){
    super.onPause()
    sensorMgr?.unregisterListener(this@MainActivity)
}
```

And you don't need to handle it on `onDestory()`

Comment: What about `super.onResume()` and `super.onPause()`? Where should I add it? before or after? And What about `onDestroy()`?

Comment: Is there any reason to call it before? And I don't need to handle it `onDestory()`?

Comment: can you please post your updated code in question @c-an